# Get reference of window object from a dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code like this

```
var element = $("elementId");
```

I got the reference to the element (which is a div).

Now I need to get the reference to the window in which this div element resides. But the problem is, here the $ is passed from a different window. So now the element resides in a different window.

How to get reference to that window object which contains this div element? Pls Help.

Comment: `$("elementId")[0].ownerDocument.defaultView`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Can you explain what is a 'window' for you ? However, if you are asking to get the parent of the element, then `element.parent()` will do the work fine.

Ho, and if `elementId` is an id, you should write $('#elementId')

Comment: @RobW That's awesome, I've never seen that before. Just note, from MDN - "According to quirksmode, defaultView is not supported in IE until IE 9." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.defaultView

Comment: @Ian Use `.parentWindow` for IE.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Get a reference to the DOM node, use the [`ownerDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.ownerDocument) property to get a reference to the document, then read its [`defaultView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.defaultView) property ([`parentWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE8-) to get a reference to the window:

```
var $element = $('#elementId');
var element = $element[0];
// Assume that element exists, otherwise an error will be thrown at the next line
var doc = element.ownerDocument;
var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
```